# Am I using NSDictionary correctly? (taken from plist)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary

```
    -(void)setUpHorizontal {
        int i = 1;
        while (_data[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Horizontal%i", i]] != nil) {
            NSDictionary* horizontal = _data[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Horizontal%i", i]];
            _column = horizontal[@"Column"];
            _row = horizontal[@"Row"];
            NSInteger column = [_column intValue];
            NSInteger row = [_row intValue];
            [super setHBarCellState:HorizontalState forHBarCol:column andHBarRow:row];
            i++;
        }
    }

     -(instancetype)initWithDestinationIndex:(NSUInteger)levelsIndex {
         self = [super init];
         if (self) {
            NSString* filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                          pathForResource:@"Levels" ofType:@"plist"];
            NSDictionary *levels = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
            NSArray *levelsArray = levels[@"LevelsData"];
            _data = levelsArray[levelsIndex];
         }
     return self;
     }
```

First off, the stringWithFormat: method is looking for the string of an **NSDictionary* called 'Horizontal%i"**.  I need to go through 2 more of those **(Horizontal2, Horizontal3)** before the while loop ends.  _column and _row are NSNumber instance variables **(whose values are taken from the a plist with key titles "Column" and "Row").**

**Each time a loop like this runs, those two keys are sub-children of their respective dictionary (in this case, Horizontal%i).**

**_data is the primary NSDictionary***.  I use it an an instance variable although I don't even know if that's possible **(or efficient for that matter)**.  I use it as such because those 'setUpHorizontal' and all the other methods I have need to access the _data.

Imagine that 'Horizontal' represents a state.  Well there are 14 other states where I perform the same task.  The end result is to get specific column and row values for a particular state into the 'set....CellState: for...Col: and...Row:' method.  That way, via the other methods I built, their respective images can be displayed on the screen.

**Let me know if any of this is unclear.  I just want to know if the code you see is actually doing anything of value.**

Here's the plist:
        
        
        
        
    LevelsData
    
        
            StoneOne
            
                Column
                2
                Row
                2
            
            StoneTwo
            
                Column
                3
                Row
                4
            
            Target
            
                Column
                0
                Row
                1
            
            Horizontal1
            
                Column
                2
                Row
                1
            
            Horizontal2
            
                Column
                0
                Row
                0
            
            Horizontal3
            
                Column
                0
                Row
                3
            
            GhostHorizontal1
            
                Column
                1
                Row
                3
            
            GhostHorizontal2
            
                Column
                4
                Row
                0
            
            Vertical1
            
                Column
                3
                Row
                0
            
            Vertical2
            
                Column
                1
                Row
                2
            
            Vertical3
            
                Column
                3
                Row
                4
            
            Intersector1
            
                Column
                0
                Row
                3
            
            Up1
            
                Column
                1
                Row
                2
            
            Down1
            
                Column
                3
                Row
                3
            
            Left1
            
                Column
                0
                Row
                0
            
            Left2
            
                Column
                2
                Row
                1
            
            Left3
            
                Column
                1
                Row
                3
            
            TopR1
            
                Column
                3
                Row
                0

Comment: Can you show us how does `Levels.plist` look like?

Comment: How do I do that?  Sorry, I've never dealt with this situation before..

Comment: You are parsing a file called `Levels.plist`, right? Can you copy/paste its structure here? It will help us understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hopefully you can see the plist normally if you edit it.  I didn't know how to display it as I would see it in Xcode

Comment: Go to Xcode and right click on the plist file. Then click "Open As -> Source Code" and copy/paste it here.

Comment: where do you mean here?  I tried to paste it in the edit of my question

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, everything looks ok. Although you can use `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock` on `_data` for enumeration rather than using a `while`.